# Margin & Float Pixelate Linear Gradient (Chrome bug?)

Tags: css, google-chrome

In the following fiddle, the block looks good if you comment out the margin/float properties of the CSS.

Why is the gradient messed up with them there?

By "Messed up" I mean (notice the lines are not smooth):

[image]

(Please don't try to fix it in a workaround, I know how to do that and that's not the point of this question.)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/dp9o7p9d/1/)

```
.rec {
   margin: 10px; 
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(134, 108, 83) 0%, rgb(134, 108, 83) 12.5%, rgb(127, 107, 86) 12.5%, rgb(127, 107, 86) 25%, rgb(228, 175, 104) 25%, rgb(228, 175, 104) 37.5%, rgb(254, 221, 139) 37.5%, rgb(254, 221, 139) 50%, rgb(48, 44, 43) 50%, rgb(48, 44, 43) 62.5%, rgb(237, 232, 226) 62.5%, rgb(237, 232, 226) 75%, rgb(200, 193, 192) 75%, rgb(200, 193, 192) 87.5%, rgb(157, 151, 151) 87.5%, rgb(157, 151, 151) 100%);
}
```

I'm doing this test on **Chrome** 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

**Update:**

As Lester pointed out, `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` fixes this. Turns out that `-webkit-transform: translate3D(0,0,0);` fixes this as well. Maybe any `-webkit` based addressing command will do the trick for some reason.

Still, the original question remains unanswered, but with the addition of this puzzle.

Comment: I see no difference in the gradient if I remove those two properties.

Comment: @Harry Yeah one moment.

Comment: @sma Updated, is that more clear?

Comment: @OmriAharon: Ok, I do see lines that are not smooth but they are different from the image you've shown (and they are there with/without the float and margin). Interesting and even more strange is that if I add a `border` (any border) there are no jagged lines issue.

Comment: Me too. I see the lines smooth with or without float and margin. Firefox v44.0.2

Comment: @Harry Updated with my browser. Maybe it's a browser/monitor thing?

Comment: @OmriAharon: I wouldn't rule that out. I am using a old Chrome (v43) now (but as I mentioned in my previous comment, adding a border fixes all). One more weird thing is the jagged lines get different if the result area in fiddle is increased/decreased.

Comment: I see now in chrome and I see the same as your shared image, but if I remove float and margin, the image is the same. It seems that chrome hasn't got a good antialiasing system (it's true in fonts, but I'm not sure in gradients). In firefox all is render fine

Comment: @Harry he is asking for an explanation not a workaround. However, it seems a bug or a problem with antialiasing system in Chrome. Chrome renders fonts with a poor antialiasing system, maybe this is controlled by the same.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: I know and that's why I hadn't added that as an answer but it doesn't mean I shouldn't mention it right? Maybe that information could be useful for somebody else's analysis :)

Comment: Allright @Harry! I agree with you :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Its got more weirder now. Backface visibility (kudos to the user for guessing that) solves it but how on earth does adding a border fix that would be known only to Chrome developers :D

Comment: Maybe the explanation in the comment of the answer is true, and the border converts the element in a flat element. Only chrome developers can tell us. But I'm proud of using firefox, this kind of things are less often in firefox than in Chrome. Thank you Mozilla community!! You are building a better and free world.

Answer (score 6):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

This may solve the problem in chrome, because in other browser the aliased works fine

Comment: Allright, it seems that is fixed, but why? Is chrome messing up the back and the front of the element? Is chrome a bug itself? Thank you :)

Comment: Well, I don't know in a 100% but the reason may be that a gradient (mathematically speaking) sometimes are NOT flat, and this may lead to a kind of 3d layers, so browsers do not render it well so it's important to 'makes them flat' to avoid those messy edges, so the backface hide those :)

Comment: It makes sense. Brain note for the future :)

Comment: Thanks, your workaround is indeed better than my workaround :) I'm leaving it open, hoping for someone from the Chrome team to explain what's going on here.

Comment: @Lester Why not ? :) Btw, `-webkit-transform: translate3D(0,0,0);` also fixes this. Maybe it just needs a jumpstart in the `webkit` engine?

Comment: http://adrianroselli.com/2014/10/linear-gradient-problems-in-chrome.html I found this post, maybe it will help you :)